# Java send Live Video InputStream to Red5 Media Server

Tags: java, inputstream, h.264, red5, rtmp

I have an `InputStream` from a Socket in Java.
The `InputStream` is a H.264 video live stream. I would like to send this Video `InputStream` to a red5 Media Server, so that other clients can watch it.

I found this example

```
package com.ryong21.example.publisher;import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import org.red5.server.messaging.IMessage;
import org.red5.server.stream.message.RTMPMessage;
import org.red5.server.stream.provider.FileProvider;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Publisher {
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Publisher.class);

            String publishName = "test";
            String localFile = "2.mp3";
            String host = "rtmpxn.91kge.com";
            int port = 1935;
            String app = "live";

            IMessage msg = null;
            int timestamp = 0;
            int lastTS = 0;

            PublishClient client = new PublishClient();

            client.setHost(host);
            client.setPort(port);
            client.setApp(app);                    

            client.start(publishName, "live", null);

            while(client.getState() != PublishClient.PUBLISHED){
                    Thread.sleep(500);
            }

            FileProvider fp = new FileProvider(new File(localFile));        

            Date begin = new Date();
            log.debug(begin.toString());

            while(true){
                    msg = fp.pullMessage(null);

                    if(msg == null){
                            log.debug("done!");
                            break;
                    }
                    timestamp = ((RTMPMessage)msg).getBody().getTimestamp();
                    Thread.sleep(timestamp - lastTS);
                    lastTS = timestamp;
                    client.pushMessage( msg);
            }      
            Date end = new Date();
            log.debug(end.toString());
            client.stop();
    }
```

}`

My problem is how to use this with a Sockets InputStream, instead of the File used in FileProvider. The InputStream is already in H.264 encoded.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, after digging a little deeper into video streaming, i found out that i ll first have to convert the InputStream to a container format file. Possible container formats are .mp4 or .flv

Having created the container file, i can now publish it to the red5 media server.